# Properly formatting the output to a file

Tags: python

I'm parsing URL's and saving them to a file.  The code I have works fine on Windows, but on Ubuntu it adds a little 'u' to the front of each line

```
import re

reports = "C:\Users/_____/Desktop/Reports/"
string = "Here is a string to test.  http://www.blah.com  &  http://2nd.com"
url_match = re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', string)
print url_match

if url_match != []:
    with open(reports + "_URLs.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write('{}'.format(url_match).replace(',', "\n").replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", '').replace(' ', '').__add__("\n"))
```

[image]

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix that?  Thanks

Comment: How about `text_file.write('{}'.format(url_match).replace(',', "\n").replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("'", '').replace(' ', '').__add__("\n")[1:])` (notice the `[1:]` at the end)

Comment: `'{}'.format(url_match)` is just `url_match`, by the way.

Comment: Also, you should use `+` instead of `.__add__()`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 No, it isn't and that's part of the problem. `url_match` is a list, the format makes it the string representation of the list and then OP tries to hack that out with a bunch of replaces. The question isn't why linux doesn't work but why windows does.

Comment: @tdelaney - Oh, it's being used instead of `str()`? And then of course the `list` syntax features have to be removed. That is indeed a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'{}'.format(url_match)` turns the `url_match` list into its human-readable string which you then use some convoluted string replacements to turn back into a list of lines to write. Somewhere along the line you get a unicode string, hence the 'u'. I'm not going to speculate why that happens because the real solution is to just process the list:

```
import re

# reports = "C:\Users/_____/Desktop/Reports/"
reports = "" # for test
string = "Here is a string to test.  http://www.blah.com  &  http://2nd.com"
url_match = re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', string)
print url_match
if url_match:
    with open(reports + "_URLs.txt", "a") as text_file:
        for url in url_match:
            text_file.write(url + '\n')
```

Comment: Yes this works... Thank you!   >>  "and then OP tries to hack that out with a bunch of replaces."   :-)  I'll get there.   Thanks again

Comment: I didn't mean to sound so harsh! Sometimes if it looks like a total hack its a good idea to go back to the original data and look for a cleaner way.

Comment: Also if you find you still have unicode data coming in, maybe because the input file has this or you're pasting from the clipboard you may want to insert a `url_match = [item.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for item in url_match]`